# asp.net Item Template Button - Disable, Run Code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an item template which has 4 buttons as a result of the template and SQL Code retrieving the columns.  The button at the top is a "submit" button that submits changes to the database.

The code currently runs on Click (OnClick) and runs a subroutine called UpdateData.   However, users are double-clicking that button and causing problems.  I need to be able to disable the button, run the code, and re-enable the button but can't seem to figure out how :(

I know that I could use OnClientClick="this.disabled=true" to disable the button, but then the  UpdateData sub wouldn't run.

I tried using sender.enabled=false at the beginning of the UpdateData sub and then setting to true at the end - but the user can still click the button anyway :(

How do I couple these things together to get this to work properly?

The button does NOT have it's own event because it is a template item and is the reason for using OnClick="UpdateData"

The button looks like this:

```
<asp:button id=cmdResult1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="UpdateData></asp:button>
```

Comment: This is in fact  common problem and there are many ways (often clunky ) to deal with it, depending on how you are handling the "UpdateData" . For example, are you then doing a AJAX style partial PostBack?

Comment: No - doing a full postback from the button.  No AJAX on this app at all.

Comment: Should have explained better:  I'm iterating through the textboxes, updating the variables (in SQL), and posting back.

Comment: doesn't sound like your update statement should take too long ? are you redirecting or posting back to same page?